# PHP joomla Migration

Tags: php, joomla, migration

After Migrating joomla 1.5 to 1.7 with the use of JUpgrade gives Error : Database Error: Unable to connect to the Database: Could not connect to MySQL.Any Idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the config file related to the database, it might have been reset.

the configuration file is called configuration.php and should be in the public_html directory:
some code like this should be there:

```
var $host = 'localhost'; // Leave it to localhost if you are unsure
var $user = 'your-database-user'; // This should be changed to yours
var $password = 'yourpass'; // Change it to the password for the database user
var $db = 'your-database-name'; // Change it to the name of your database
```

please edit those 4 entries.

Comment: How to see the config file, please gives step to see config file

Comment: do you have some FTP access to the server?

Comment: its same as you have suggested

Comment: the file should be sitting on the server so if you can access the server you should be able to modify it using FTP, SSH or whatever

Comment: thats i know, but its ok, the variable is ok

Comment: Are you sure MySQL is running then?

Comment: yes, found its my problem, I am seeing at older version of configuration.php

Answer (score 1):

There will be file named as `configuration.php` inside your project-folder.

In that file look for the variables `$host`, `$user`, `$db` and other related variables.

Comment: its ok, any other place where it mismatch ?

Comment: after changing configuration.php, still you are facing any problem?